# Running Discord.py client & Uvicorn app simultaneously

Tags: python, discord.py, fastapi

I've been trying to implement a Discord.py bot with a basic FastAPI application.
The API runs with a uvicorn.Server class from [uvicorn#742](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/742#issuecomment-674411676), with a run_in_thread() function, so both processes can't really hold each other.

Unfortunately, when I run both apps together.. it seems that the Discord client is preventing the API from receiving web requests, I believe that's because the bot client uses a bunch of network frameworks. I've tried multiple approaches in solving this issue, but just can't seem to find a right solution.

The root directory contains 2 files.. **api.py** just for the FastAPI app, and **main.py** for everything else (client, classes, etc). But I will try to just provide the important parts.

```py
# main.py

from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import uvicorn, contextlib, time

client = Bot() # just a basic discord.ext.commands.Bot class, nothing fancy here.

@client.event
async def on_ready(self):
    print(f"Bot online, logged in as {client.user}")

# https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/742#issuecomment-674411676
class Webhook(uvicorn.Server):
    def install_signal_handlers(self): pass

    @contextlib .contextmanager
    def run_in_thread(self):
        thread = Thread(target = self.run)
        thread.start()
        try:
            while not self.started:
                time.sleep(1e-3)
            yield
        finally:
            self.should_exit = True
            thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_server = Webhook(
        config = uvicorn.Config("api:app", # you can guess what api.py contains already.
            host = "127.0.0.1", 
            port = 8000, 
            log_level = "info", 
            loop = "asyncio",
            workers = 3)
        )
    
    with api_server.run_in_thread():
        client.run(TOKEN)
```

I've played with this a lot, either the bot or the API works in each method. My best guess is that it has to do with event loops, uvicorn.Server loop seems to be hard to handle, but I'm only intermediate with that.